# Unknown error in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

So I posted last night with some issues, but my code was a mess so I re-wrote it. First of all what it needs to do is print a 3x3 grid of numbers, then find all o the saddles and print them. (saddles are numbers that are lowest in column but highest in row).

When ran, this is the console output:

```
7 1 18
15 10 3
0 15 2
```

The saddles are:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) int[], int[]
    The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) int[], int[]
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from int[] to int
    The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) int[], int[]
    The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) int[], int[]
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from int[] to int
    The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) int[], int[]
    The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) int[], int[]
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from int[] to int
    at Main.findLowest(Main.java:66)
    at Main.findSaddles(Main.java:54)
    at Main.main(Main.java:16)
```

Here is my code, bit messy but haven't had time to clean it up yet:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Random;

    public class Main {

    static  int[][] Grid = new int[3][3];
    static ArrayList<Integer> Saddles = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static Random random = new Random();
    static int currentColumn; //will be use by various methods to fill/read from array


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        fillArray();
        printArray();
        findSaddles();
    }//end of main()


    //fill the array with random "ints"
    public static void fillArray(){
        currentColumn = 0;
        int indexsFilled = 0;

        while(indexsFilled != 9){
            Grid[0][currentColumn] = random.nextInt(21);
            Grid[1][currentColumn] = random.nextInt(21);
            Grid[2][currentColumn] = random.nextInt(21);
            indexsFilled += 3;
            currentColumn += 1;         
        }//end of while loop    
    }//end fillArray()


    //print array's contents
    public static void printArray(){
        currentColumn = 0;
        int indexsPrinted = 0;

        while(indexsPrinted != 9){
            System.out.print(Grid[0][currentColumn] + " ");
            System.out.print(Grid[1][currentColumn] + " ");
            System.out.print(Grid[2][currentColumn] + "\n");
            indexsPrinted += 3;
            currentColumn += 1;         
        }//end of while loop
    }//end of printArray()


    public static void findSaddles(){
        System.out.println("The saddles are: ");

        currentColumn = 0;
        findLowest(currentColumn);
        findLowest(currentColumn + 1);
        findLowest(currentColumn + 2);

        for(int i = 0; i <= Saddles.size(); i++){
            System.out.print(Saddles.get(i) + " ");
        }

    }//end find Saddles

    public static void findLowest(int columnNumber){
        int lowest;
        if(Grid[0] < Grid[1] || Grid[0] < Grid[2]){
            lowest = Grid[0];
        }
        else{
            if(Grid[1] < Grid[0] || Grid[1] < Grid[2]){
                lowest = Grid[1];
            }
            else{
                if(Grid[2] < Grid[1] || Grid[2] < Grid[1])
                    lowest = Grid[2];
            }//end branching if loop
        }
        Saddles.add(lowest);
    }//end of findLowest

}//end of Main
```

Comment: 1) the errors are telling you **exactly** what's wrong -- you're trying to use less than and greater than on arrays, not on the items held by the arrays, and 2) you're trying to run code that won't compile -- never do this. Fix the compilation problems first.

Comment: From a glance, your `findLowest()` function implementation seems wrong. Your algorithm tries to compare two arrays instead of two numbers.

Comment: `"bit messy but haven't had time to clean it up yet:"` -- please take the time to fix this before posting here. This implies something like, "I don't have time to fix this, but I expect you to have time to read it". We greatly appreciate it when you in fact **do** take the time to make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: I don't understand why people post these kinds of questions. Did you even read the error? You either didn't care to read it, or you did and you are still confused.

Comment: @ChrisLondon I think you should take some time to go through [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) and understand how to program in Java. **All your questions** are about some basic Java code! Also, I recommend you read [this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks the **minimal understanding** of the problem being solved.

Comment: @Hovercraft, Sorry, I didn't understand what it was saying. Believe me I sat there trying to figure it out from the error message but just didn't get it, as for the messyness I was implying variable names, giving them more suitable names and generally making sure it is neat and tidy, I personally don't see why my code is hard to read?

Mike, well I obviously read it and was still confused. Bit of a stupid thing to say really, wasn't it?

Baranka, yeah I am still learning. Been trying to teach myself for a long time but just can't get the hang of it.  I'll keep trying I guess.

Comment: @ChrisLondon Really, check the Java Tutorials, follow them, do the exercises... It is not wrong to learn by yourself, but it is not a good thing to write code before you understand how the language works

Comment: Understand that most of us are self-taught, myself included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a 2D array `Grid`, but in `findLowest`, you are using only one array index to access values to compare with `<`.  That retrieves the 1D array within the 2D array.

Use two array indices to access the value from a 2D array.

```
if(Grid[0][columnNumber] < Grid[1][columnNumber] ||
   Grid[0][columnNumber] < Grid[2][columnNumber]){
```

and likewise for other `Grid` 2D array accesses in that method.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare arrays, and that is not defined in java:

```
//...
static  int[][] Grid = new int[3][3];
//...
if(Grid[0] < Grid[1] || Grid[0] < Grid[2]) { // This comparissons are impossible
    lowest = Grid[0];
}
```

You cannot compare arrays directly. You need to compare each entry.

Answer (score 0):

All your errors seem to be from trying to `Grid[i]` (for any `i`) as an `int`. For instance, you have:

```
if(Grid[0] < Grid[1] || Grid[0] < Grid[2]){
    lowest = Grid[0];
}
```

but `Grid` is an array of arrays, so `Grid[0]` (for instance) is an array, not an `int` value.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void findLowest(int columnNumber){
    int lowest;
    if(Grid[0] < Grid[1] || Grid[0] < Grid[2]){
        lowest = Grid[0];
    }
    else{
        if(Grid[1] < Grid[0] || Grid[1] < Grid[2]){
            lowest = Grid[1];
        }
        else{
            if(Grid[2] < Grid[1] || Grid[2] < Grid[1])
                 lowest = Grid[2];
        }//end branching if loop
    }
    Saddles.add(lowest);
}//end of findLowest
```

You're not making use of your 'columnNumber' parameter at all. You need to use it to reference which array within 'Grid' you're referring to, and then perform the comparisons on the elements of that array. A corrected example:

```
public static void findLowest(int columnNumber)
{
    // ...
    if (Grid[columnNumber][0] < Grid[columnNumber][1] || Grid[columnNumber][0] < Grid[columnNumber][2])
    // Rest of your code in a similar style
}
```